# How do you sync files between perforce and git repos

Tags: github, synchronization, perforce, rsync, git-p4

I have a set of files in a Perforce project that get updated by users from time to time. I have a copy of those set of files in a directory in a separate Github project. I want to be able to automatically sync those files in my Github repo or my local copy in my workstation any time there is a change made to those files in the perforce repository.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look a `p4 trigger` command. It is synonymous with `git hooks` and lets you run a script that pushes the assets to your github repo every time they change.

Answer (score 0):

You may also wish to think about Git Fusion, which is a connector/bridge between Perforce and Git.

This KB provides some examples of sharing work between a Helix Server and a public repo:
  http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/7481/